# swift - how to get audio output from mic on iphone at 8khz sample rate with buffer size of 16ms & 1 channel?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation, avaudioengine

For a demo app on iphone, I want to get audio output from mic at 8khz, buffer size of 16ms so that it gives 128bytes of framelength at a time.

I've tried this AVAudioEngine by installing a tap on the input node but there is no way of setting sample rate and buffer size. Any suggestions on how to achieve 128 bytes output?

The sample rate can be different but I need 128bytes with 16ms.

Thanks

```
private func startRecording() throws {
    checkPermission()
    if !self.hasPermissionToRecord {
        return
    }
    if engine == nil {
        engine = AVAudioEngine()
    }
    let inputNode = engine.inputNode
    let microphoneOutputFormat: AVAudioFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    let microphoneAudioStream = microphoneOutputFormat.formatDescription.audioStreamBasicDescription
    let microphoneSampleRate = microphoneAudioStream!.mSampleRate

    var mulawDescription = AudioStreamBasicDescription(
        mSampleRate: 8000,
        mFormatID: kAudioFormatULaw,
        mFormatFlags: 0,
        mBytesPerPacket: 1,
        mFramesPerPacket: 1,
        mBytesPerFrame: 1,
        mChannelsPerFrame: 1,
        mBitsPerChannel: 8,
        mReserved: 0
    )
        
    let mulawFormat = AVAudioFormat(streamDescription: &mulawDescription)!
    converter = AVAudioConverter(from: microphoneOutputFormat, to: mulawFormat)
        
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: defaultUlawBufferSize, format: microphoneOutputFormat) { [self] (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) in
            
    let secondsInBuffer:Float64 = Float64(buffer.frameLength) / Float64(microphoneSampleRate);
    let ulawBufferSize = UInt32(8000 * secondsInBuffer) // 800
            
    // conversion - downsample
    guard let mulawBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: converter.outputFormat, frameCapacity: 800) else {
        return
    }
    var outError: NSError? = nil
    let microphoneInputBlock: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { (inNumbPackets, outStatus) -> AVAudioBuffer? in
        outStatus.pointee = AVAudioConverterInputStatus.haveData
        return buffer
    }
    self.converter.convert(to: mulawBuffer, error: &outError, withInputFrom: microphoneInputBlock)
    let mulawData = Data(buffer:mulawBuffer)
    if (!(receivedAudioCallback?(mulawData) ?? false)) {
         stop()
     }
    }
    engine.prepare()
    try engine.start()
}
```

I've tried this code, after downsampling at 8khz it gives me 800bytes